# Solve $4^{138x + 75} \equiv 4^{15} \pmod{53}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to solve the equation
\begin{equation}
4^{138x + 75} \equiv 4^{15} \pmod{53}
\end{equation}
for $x$. Fermats little theorem yields $4^{52} \equiv 1 \pmod{53}$, but where do I go from here?

Comment: Since $4=2^2$, Fermat actually means that $4^{26}\equiv 1\pmod{53}$. And that still might not be the smallest "order" of $4$.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. How can I find the smallest (positive) $x$ which gives $4^x \equiv 1 \pmod{53}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^{13}=8192\equiv 30\pmod {53}$, then $2^{26}=900\equiv-1\pmod{53}$. Also, $2^4\not\equiv1\pmod{53}$. Therefore
$$2^n\equiv 1\pmod{53}\iff n\equiv 0\pmod{52}$$

Now,

$$2^{276x+150}\equiv 2^{30}\pmod{53}$$

$$276x+150\equiv 30\pmod {52}$$

$$69x\equiv -30\pmod {13}$$

$$23x\equiv -10\pmod{13}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I'm not really familiar with what you do in the second step of the calculation above. Is it a general rule that if you have $a^x \equiv a^y \pmod{p}$, you can set $x \equiv y \pmod{p}$?

Comment: No. Note the change from mod 53 to mod 52. You should know about primitive roots mod $p$ to be assigned this problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, actually, we haven't learned about primitive roots mod $p$ yet. That's why I found this problem so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

We have $4^{13} \equiv -1 \bmod 53$ (*).
This means that the order of $4 \bmod 53$ is $26$.

Therefore, $138x + 75 \equiv 15 \bmod 26$, which reduces to $8x \equiv 18 \bmod 26$ and to $-5x \equiv 5 \bmod 13$, which is trivial to solve.

(*) I see no way to avoid a computation here.